# Search in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to Search in my Table. I write follow Code :

```
var w = from act in Movie_List.Actors
                     where act.Actor_Name == Snametxt.Text
                     select new {act.Actor_Name};
Acttxt.Text= w.SingleOrDefault().Actor_Name;
```

this code work only for FIRST search and when I want to search again , appear exception .

Exception :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve problem finally.

you must remove binding after binding data .

```
            try
            {
                Acttxt.DataBindings.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

before bind control too database write this code for any control.

Answer (score 0):

you gotta first check to see if w contains any element :

```
var w = from act in Movie_List.Actors
                     where act.Actor_Name == Snametxt.Text
                     select new {act.Actor_Name};
if (w.Any())
   Acttxt.Text= w.SingleOrDefault().Actor_Name;
```